# Sorting vectors in Clojure map of vectors

Tags: sorting, vector, clojure

I have a map of vectors, like this:

```
{2 ["a" "c" "b"], 1 ["z" "y" "x"]}
```

I want to get a map that is sorted by keys, and then each corresponding vector is also sorted, like this:

```
{1 ["x" "y" "z"], 2 ["a" "b" "c"]}
```

I know I can sort by keys by doing `(into (sorted-map) themap)`, and I know that I can supply a transducer to `into`, but I'm coming up short as to exactly how the transducer should look. Here's a transducer I've tried:

```
(defn xform [entry]
  (vector (first entry) (vec (sort (second entry)))))
```

However, when I try to apply it to my map, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.core$conj__4345
```

How can I get this to work? Is there a better way then using `into` with a transducer?

Comment: You almost got it. You just missed using the `map` function to create a `map` transducer. `(map xform)`, though you shouldn't call this function an xform since it's not a transducer yet but just a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
(into (sorted-map)
      (map (fn [[k v]] [k (vec (sort v))]))
      {2 ["a" "c" "b"], 1 ["z" "y" "x"]})
```